# requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS) Deprecated

Tags: android

Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS is depricated. What are we supposed to use to show a progressbar under the toolbar?

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

> public static final int FEATURE_PROGRESS = 2 Flag for the progress
>   indicator feature.
>
> Deprecated No longer supported starting in API 21.

Comment: Add a `ProgressBar` to your UI at a suitable location.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is it compatible with Android API 19 and 20, or there is a way to support those two platforms if we use the `ProgressBar`? We are aiming for max compatibility.

Comment: @tom_mai78101: API 20 is 1st-generation Android Wear, and I doubt that this window feature works on it. API 19 supports this window feature. `ProgressBar` has existed since API Level 1.